# In the sentence below is "the" required before huge and why?

Tags: science

Is it correct to write

> Newcastle disease is economically significant because of the huge mortality and morbidity associated with it.

Comment: I would certainly employ an article in the circumstances, but I don't think it is essential.

Comment: Hi, Monica, and welcome to EL&U.

Comment: I upvoted Susan's reply, below. If this is a formal paper, I would go with "the extremely high rate of mortality and morbidity". On the content: I have seen Newcastle disease ravage populations which is a shame because it's so easily preventable. Unfortunately, those who most need the inoculant are often least able to afford it.

Comment: I am American and think the *the* is necessary in this case. Like @David, I find the use of *huge* here odd.

Answer (score 12):

It is, because *mortality* is made definite by *associated with it*. When such modification occurs after the noun, it is known as 'cataphoric'.

Comment: I did a quick search of the British Medical literature, then one of British newspapers, and found that it is no different in GB than in the US. In this case, it's not a matter of grammar, but one of common usage. Or, one can say it is ungrammatical in hundreds of English usages weekly. I maintain the former.

Answer (score 3):

To my ear, it sounds strange. Maybe it's just an American thing, but we tend to refer to mortality and morbidity without an article, and when we use *the*, it is usually expressed as *the _ rate*.

> - Placental Abruption and Perinatal Mortality in the United States
> - They took into consideration not just mortality and morbidity, but also quality of life, which is an essential measure...
> - *The rate* of coronary heart disease mortality was greater among lumberjacks...
> - We find that for high-seniority male workers, mortality rates in the year after displacement...
> - Societies that have achieved the lowest levels of maternal mortality have done so by...
> - What is *the mortality and morbidity rate* of thyroidectomy?
> - The realities of maternal mortality and morbidity in the developing world...

Comment: American here, sounds weird to me WITHOUT the 'the'.

Comment: It might be because I'm a physician. We don't use the article, not in speaking and certainly not in writing about morbidity, mortality, or both. The only time it sounds 'normal' is if one starts the sentence with M/M; then, we *might* say, *The mortality* (now, see? I wanted to type *rate*). We have M&M rounds. Not *the* M&M rounds. *While TB mortality has declined fairly steadily, morbidity has been rising.* —Time. *That's* not limited to medical professions.

Comment: I think Barrie England's answer shows the difference -- yes, if you drop the 'associated with it' portion of the sentence, the definite article sounds odd. With it, leaving off the article sounds odd.

Comment: @PeterL - I'm sorry, but I disagree with Barrie as well.